# Best place to intercept Android Activity to display another Activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

Let say my main activity is `MainActivity`, but occasionally I want to show other activities immediately after `MainActivity` is called, such as:

- `WelcomeActivity` where you must click "next next" before returning to `MainActivity`, or
- `NoticeActivity` where you can simply press BACK to return to `MainActivity`

My questions:

1. Is `onCreate()` the best place to put `if something then startActivityForResult(...)`?
2. If YES, after `startActivityForResult(...)` called, should `MainActivity.onCreate()` immediately return, or let it finish (i.e. all layout stuff done)?
3. If NO, where's the best place?

Comment: Usually you MainActivity is not the first activity, but the first with you can  interact with, or the one which you can navigate the whole app. What you are looking for can be made on the SPLASH screen, which is the first activity that you will see (usually with your logo, is the one that communicate with some endpoint, handle the tokens, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is onCreate() the best place to put if something then
>   startActivityForResult(...)?

YES, you can make call to startActivityForResult() from onCreate().

> If YES, after startActivityForResult(...) called, should
>   MainActivity.onCreate() immediately return, or let it finish (i.e. all
>   layout stuff done)?

No, untill unless you have explicity call return statement in onCreate() it will not return but let it finish all the init stuff.

> If NO, where's the best place?

Better, you make call to startActivityForResult() at end of the onCreate() after all the init statements.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the unmitigated "YES" to the first question. At least for the Welcome screen, it sounds like logic that you want to run only when the app is launched. onCreate of MainActivity will be called in many more cases than just at launch time, including when the device is rotated and (depending on the launch mode) when you go back to the main activity from another activity. In that case it would be more correct/efficient to have a separate launch activity that starts Main, Welcome or another activity based on your conditions.